# Why is my get request returning undefined in my image file tree?

Tags: angular

I have not been able to find anything similar to this issue...

I am able to fetch information from my REST API, however when I am fetching my image there is something weird happening... Never seen anything like this.

It should be showing something like

```
localhost:3000/images/image.jpg
```

However, what is showing is error code 404 and the url looks like

```
localhost:3000/undefinedimages/image.jpg
```

my request is as follows

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.userprovider.getUsers()
      .subscribe((users) => {
              this.users = users
              console.log(this.users);
          },
          errmess => this.userErrMess = < any > errmess);
  }
```

getUsers function looks like this...

```
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
return this.http.get<User[]>(baseURL + 'users')
  .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
 .catch(this.handleError);

 }
```

has anyone experienced an issue like this before?

Edit:

Base URL is defined as follows :

```
export const baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

imported into app.module.ts as follows:

```
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';
```

...

```
 providers: [

...
{ provide: 'BaseURL', useValue: baseURL },
...
]
```

Comment: how is your request connected to the image url?

Comment: in html document I have "{{ BaseURL + users[0].profileImg }}" BaseURL is set to "http://localhost:3000/"

Comment: then your BaseUrl is definitely `undefined`

Comment: I am not having any other issues with baseurl. Maybe I am just missing something. See edit.

Comment: can you access your BaseURL anywhere else in your html document, where it is not undefined?

Comment: I had another page that was able to access image. I just solved my own problem.... I was not injecting BaseURL. Geez that is such a silly mistake I cannot believe that I was looking at it for so long! What @smnbbrv was saying was correct. While I technically had defined baseurl, I was not injecting it so my page had no idea what it was.... Thank you guys for you r help. Apologies for my ignorance!

Comment: Also, @smnbbrv if you want to suggest making sure that BaseURL is injected properly as an answer I can mark it as correct so you can get credit, since you were the one who put it in perspective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the BaseURL is undefined, that is why actually the problem happens. Try to just print it within the document to see whether it is true (`{{ BaseURL }}`).